# Get int from bytes in Java, encoded first in C#

Tags: c#, java, android, endianness

I am having a problem converting an int from a byte array first encoded in C#. I first convert it into big-endian because Java works in big-edian rather than small. The following code encodes the into into bytes

```
    Console.WriteLine("A new data client has connected!");
    byte[] welcomeMessage = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Welcome young chap! Please let me know about anything you need!");

    welcomeMessage = Byte.add(BitConverter.GetBytes(System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(20)), welcomeMessage);
```

Byte.add appends the two arrays together. This works because I have used it between C# to C#. The welcome message is first loaded with a header byte to let the client know what the information is. I get strange values on the java side when I try to decode it. I am not sure if I am decoding or encoding improperly. The java side is such. This is running on an android device:

```
   if (ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getInt() == 20)
   {
          latestMessage = new String(buffer); 
   }
   latestMessage = String.valueOf(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getInt(0)); //Lets me see what value this is. Cant attach debugger for some reason ATM.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) can be configured to decode multi-byte values as either big or little endian using the [`order()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) method.

For example:

```
final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

final int i = bb.getInt();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class can be of assistance. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597715/difference-between-c-sharp-and-java-big-endian-bytes-using-miscutil).

Comment: Hey I just realized I forgot to include the line which converts the header int into bytes. I have changed it accordingly.